# IBOutlet not working when trying to adjust subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

So my outlets are as follows, and yes they are connected in my .xib file:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *savedReadings;
IBOutlet UIButton *beginReading;
```

Here's my .m file:

```
 if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){

        _background.hidden = NO;
        _background2.hidden = YES;
        _PalmFrame.hidden = YES;

    }else{

        [beginReading setFrame:CGRectMake(beginReading.frame.origin.x, beginReading.frame.origin.y-1500, beginReading.frame.size.width, beginReading.frame.size.height)];
        [savedReadings setFrame:CGRectMake(savedReadings.frame.origin.x, savedReadings.frame.origin.y-1500, savedReadings.frame.size.width, savedReadings.frame.size.height)];
        _background2.hidden = NO;
        _background.hidden = YES;
        _PalmFrame.hidden = NO;
}
```

for some reason every time I try to make an adjustment to the y-axis placement of the button it doesn't budge. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you detecting the screen size, in code? Using struts / springs (Or if you're on iOS5 or later) auto layout would do this for you?

Comment: Check once above lines executed or not.. also Verify you outlets correctly configured or not most of the times that happens!!!

Comment: @Tander Yeah, I've been wrestling with Auto-Layout to be honest. I'm having a hard time making my buttons stick to the superview so that once viewed in the 3.5 inch screen the buttons move up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a primary step check these things

1. Check your lines  executed or not..
2. Verify your outlets correctly configured or not most of the times that happens!!!

If above two steps correctly done then go to your storyboard or interface builder and remove savedReadings, beginReading buttons auto layouts, you will get expected output.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I had it in Auto-Layout! Doy!